# SQL Optimizer / Execution Plan - Repeated Subqueries

Tags: sql, sqlite, query-optimization

**NOTE:** I'm currently running my queries in question on a sqlite3 DB, though answers from expertise in any other DBMS will be welcome insight...

I was wondering if the query optimizer makes any attempt to identify repeated queries/subqueries and run them only once if so.

Here is my example query:

```
SELECT *
  FROM table1 AS t1
 WHERE t1.fk_id =
 (
    SELECT t2.fk_id
      FROM table2 AS t2
     WHERE t2.id = 1111
 )
 OR t1.fk_id =
 (
    SELECT local_id 
      FROM ID_MAP
     WHERE remote_id =
     (
        SELECT t2.fk_id
          FROM table2 AS t2
         WHERE t2.id = 1111
     )
 );
```

Will the nested query

```
SELECT t2.fk_id
  FROM table2 AS t2
 WHERE t2.id = 1111
```

be run only once (and its results cached for further access) ?

Its not a big deal in this example, since its a simple query that executes only twice, however I need it to run
about 4-5 more times (x2, twice for each child record, so 8-10 really) in my actual program (its grabbing all child records (table1)
associated to a parent record (table2), bound by a foreign key. Its also checking an id mapping table to make sure it queries
for both a locally generated id, as well as the real/updated/new key).

I really appreciate any help with this, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite has a very simple query optimizer, and does not even try to detect identical subqueries:

```
> create table t(x);
> explain query plan
  select * from t
  where x in (select x from t) or
        x in (select x from t);
0|0|0|SCAN TABLE t (~500000 rows)
0|0|0|EXECUTE LIST SUBQUERY 1
1|0|0|SCAN TABLE t (~1000000 rows)
0|0|0|EXECUTE LIST SUBQUERY 2
2|0|0|SCAN TABLE t (~1000000 rows)
```

The same applies to CTEs and views; if the performance actually matters, your best bet is to create a temporary table for the result of the subquery.

Comment: "explain query plan" i didn't even know DBMS's had such a command, that's super nice. The core of the issue I'm having is syncing locally generated temp id's with the "real" ones issued back after  updates to the remote DB. Its getting tricky b/c of the parent/child foreign key relationships. Both the parent and child records can be locally generated, thus getting temp id's, and I use an ID_MAP table to keep track. I'm trying to avoid application level locks, but I'm not sure if the best bet is to use transactions (begin/commit) or nested queries to beat out the potential race conditions ?

Comment: To prevent races, use transactions. (Without explicit transactions, each command would be wrapped into an automatic transaction, so an explicit transaction around multiple commands even reduces the transaction overhead.) However, application-level locks are likely to be more efficient than [SQLite's locking scheme](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q5). In any case, don't bother optimizing until you have actual performance problems.

Comment: Ok. Does a nested query fire atomically, or does it get broken into separate statments (that in turn get wrapped into individual transactions) ? I ask b/c I'm not sure if weather or not your implying that nested queries DO NOT get fired atomically (an therefore prevent races) ? Thanks for all the help.

Comment: ... also, i'm leaning away from app-level locks b/c there are two separate process involved that communicate via a request queue that is implemented as a table. I started to code the locks in, realizing that I just ended up with race conditions on the lock table, between the fore and background processes, so decided to fix the issue where it stood (also, lock checks started pop-ing up EVERYWHERE). I still wish I could use them.

Comment: Automatic transactions go around entire statements (including any subqueries, and anything done in triggers).

Comment: Note that modern versions of SQLite support CTE. https://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html

Answer (score 1):

As you asked for insight from other DBs....

In Oracle DBMS, any independent subquery will be executed only once.

```
SELECT t2.fk_id
  FROM table2 AS t2
 WHERE t2.id = 1111  -- The result will be the same for any row in t1.
```

Dependant subqueries will need to executed repeatedly, of course.

Example of dependent subquery:

```
SELECT t2.fk_id
  FROM table2 AS t2
 WHERE t2.id = t1.t2_id  -- t1.t2_id will have different values for different rows in t1.
```

Comment: Interesting concept, in/dependent subqueries. Makes total sense, just didn't dawn on me while writing this question. Thanks!